# for all $p\in [0,1]$ there is a constant $M(p)$ such that $|f(z)|<M(p)\exp(\frac{|z|}{pR})$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n>0} \frac{c_n}{n!}z^n$ proof that for all $p\in [0,1]$ there is a constant $M(p)$ such that $|f(z)|<M(p)\exp\left(\frac{|z|}{pR}\right)$ where $R$ is the convergence radius of $\sum_{n>0} c_n z^n$ and $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

I need to use this result for an important theorem I'm working on but I couldn't prove it with an easy method

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just an hour ago or so, you asked another closely related question. You need to provide details of what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: False when $R=\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(z)=\sum_{n>0} c_n z^n$ with radius of convergence $R$ and $h(z)=e^z$, then $f=g*h=h*g$ where $*$ is the Hadamard convolution and $f$ is entire unless $R=0$

We can write $2\pi if(z)=\int_{|\zeta|=r}g(z/\zeta)h(\zeta)d\zeta/\zeta, |z|/r<R$ or also

$2\pi if(z)=\int_{|\zeta|=r}h(z/\zeta)g(\zeta)d\zeta/\zeta, r<R$

Assuming $R$ finite non-zero, $r=pR<R$ so using the second expression we get:

$2\pi|f(z)|\le \int_{|\zeta|=pR}|h(z/\zeta)||g(\zeta)||d\zeta/\zeta|$ and $|h(z/\zeta)| \le e^{|z|/(pR)}, |g(\zeta)| \le M_g(pR),  \int_{|\zeta|=pR}|d\zeta/\zeta|=2\pi$, so we get the required inequality:

$|f(z)| \le M_g(pR)e^{|z|/(pR)}$ so we can take $M_p=M_g(pR)$

If $R =\infty$ we can take $pR$ to be any positive number, so the result is that $f$ is of order at most $(1,0)$, namely $|f(z)| \le C_ae^{a|z|}, a>0$ arbitrary

(for example, take $c_n=n!/(2n)!$ and the corresponding $f$ is $\cosh \sqrt z$ which is of order $1/2$)

For $R=0$ we cannot really say anything as $f$ may or may not converge, the radius of convergence can be arbitrary, the order can be arbitrary when entire etc

Comment: dou know any method that doesn't use integration?, I can't use this tool

Comment: probably one can use various definitions of order, type in terms of coefficients and take superior limits but it's tedious that way